# package org.languagetool does not exist

Tags: java, api, netbeans-8, languagetool

I am using java languagetool for the first time. I took sample example and tried to run it. It has imported files 
`import org.languagetool.JLanguageTool;
import org.languagetool.Language;
import org.languagetool.Languages;
import org.languagetool.rules.RuleMatch;` 
I have already added "languagetool-core-2.2-sources.jar" in libraries folder, but I am getting "package org.languagetool does not exist" error. I am using netbeans, please help me in getting out of this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the ***SOURCE*** jar file, which will not help you here.  You want the packaged compiled classes:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
    <artifactId>languagetool-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am quite naive in java too. where to write this code? can you please elaborate the steps.

Comment: I assumed you were using Maven.  If not, you need to download the `languagetool-core-2.2.jar` file (note the lack of `-sources`) into your ilbrary folder.

Comment: yeah I downloaded 'languagetool-core-2.2.jar', and errors vanished. now there is error 'cannot find symbol' on 'Languages' in the code 'import org.languagetool.Languages;'

Comment: That's a separate question.  Be sure to include the exact error message (copy/paste).

Comment: Cannot find symbol                                                                             symbol : class Languages                                                                  location : package org.languagetool

Comment: Post a separate, complete question please.

Comment: Well! the IDE is telling the correct thing: I cannot see any Languages.java file in org.languagetool

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jim Garrison.  I'll post separate question on any other issue... :)